# dotnet test command started failing with MSBuild 17.4

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, azure-pipelines

We have been using ubuntu-latest agent in Azuredevops to build .netcore 3.1 projects from last one year. Things had been going very smooth until a week ago and all of the sudden, dotnet test command started failing with below error message

MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.

When we dug deeper, we found that it started happening with MSBuild version 17.4. We then tried to use older version of ubuntu agent (which is using MSBuild 17.3) and then everything went well

I would like to understand the difference between MSBuild 17.3 and 17.4 and possible solution to fix this issue. Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: You can find release notes and the source code at [https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild)

Comment: hi jegan what is the latest status of your issue, does my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your issue is caused by the [agent upgrades to support .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/upgrade-of-net-agent-for-azure-pipelines/) (.NET core 3.1 will be out of support in December). You could try to upgrade your project to .net 6 or higher.

Or you could test to add the property of `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>7.0.0<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>`.